# Winforms performance issue with Numeric up down and list box

Tags: c#, performance, listbox, numericupdown

In my Win forms app, i have a Numeric up down and a list box. 
when i increase/change value in numeric up down, that many rows are added in list box.

for ex. when i have value '1' in my numeric up down and i change the value to a larger number say '300', it adds 300 lines in the list box but it takes hell lot of time to do it.

is there any way by which i can reduce this time.
any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: If adding 300 lines is too slow, then don't add 300 lines? Or what is the problem exactly?

Comment: A. Show the code you are using. B. How long exactly; currently the length of time is a piece of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating the necessary data (or controls) that will be added first, and maybe do it in a Parallel.ForEach and afterwards add all of them.

Otherwise, only something like data virtualization available in WPF would be of help but i don't know if that exists in WinForms.

---

Try adding them "on demand". Add only the necessary few that are visible plus a few more and when the use scrolls down, add some more and so on.